# Steroids JS build app for XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build, steroids

I'm using AppGyver Steroids to create an app.  I want to build an iOS build of it so that I can open the app in XCode.  With regular PhoneGap I can simply run `phonegap build`.  I do not see this in Steroids.  I've run `phonegap build` in the Terminal, but it doesn't show native elements when I run it in the simulator (from XCode) like navigation bar.

Is this possible with Steroids?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning to use Steroids, you need to use the Steroids Build Service. To create an actual build targeting iOS platforms, please consult [their guide](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/cloud_services/ios-build-config/) on how to do this.

If you just are developing, use the deploy command to get the QR code and scan it with the AppGyver scanner application to load it temporarily to your device. Or if you want to run it in the emulator, start a steroids session from the terminal:

```
steroids connect
```

then enter

```
simulator
```

once you're in the steroids session and that should start the iOS simulator.

Not sure what you'd need xCode for in this. The beauty of steroids is that there is no iOS specific code for you to maintain (before you start messing with PhoneGap plugins, which is a different ballgame.) You can still open your html pages using xCode if you wish.

If you're asking how to have xCode do this stuff for you, then I could be wrong but I do not think there is a way. I believe the simulator that Steroids starts is the same as the xCode simulator.

Comment: I was just wanting to use XCode because there were certain iOS 7 features (like the 'blurred' translucency) that aren't shown in Steroids, and I was thinking I could change that in XCode.  It's just a minor feature so it doesn't really matter, I was just curious.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I still hope the answer was useful. A better place to ask about that might be the AppyGyver forums. The developers browse those forums, so they might be able to provide you a better answer on how to take advantage of some of those features.

Comment: You can customize the native iOS behaviour with Cordova plugins, but you cannot currently launch the Steroids project from XCode. Local builds is a feature in our future roadmap, however.